# Scan Drive Contents of Google App Domain Users

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api

From what I can tell, it looks like I need to setup a service account in the developer console to impersonate each user individually.

I need to be able to launch the script (preferably from a Web Apps Script) to scan all student Google Drives to monitor for content in violation of policy.

So, a Drive search with something like this "source:domain type:image" won't work, because those are only for shared files.

From here: https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list
I don't see a way to specify a userKey, like you can do with the Admin SDK APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, as you say you will need to use a service account. When you use a service account with the [OAuth2 library](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2), you get to set the 'Subject' (the user account that you want to impersonate). There is a [service account sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/apps-script-oauth2/blob/master/samples/GoogleServiceAccount.gs) with the library.

Here's an example of a slightly modified OAuth2.getService() that takes the user account email as a parameter. You would run this before each of your https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/files/list Drive API calls as you iterate through your user list.

```
/**
 * Configures the service.
 */
function getService(userEmail) {
  return OAuth2.createService('GoogleDrive:' + userEmail)
      // Set the endpoint URL.
      .setTokenUrl('https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token')

      // Set the private key and issuer.
      .setPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY)
      .setIssuer(CLIENT_EMAIL)

      // Set the name of the user to impersonate. This will only work for
      // Google Apps for Work/EDU accounts whose admin has setup domain-wide
      // delegation:
      // https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount#delegatingauthority
      .setSubject(userEmail)

      // Set the property store where authorized tokens should be persisted.
      .setPropertyStore(PropertiesService.getScriptProperties())

      // Set the scope. This must match one of the scopes configured during the
      // setup of domain-wide delegation.
      .setScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive');
}
```